How can I enable Camera2 API for external usb camera (on AOSP builds)?
Check kernel support for UVC device is enabled
CONFIG_USB_VIDEO_CLASS=y
CONFIG_MEDIA_USB_SUPPORT=y
Add the external camera config file and external camera library to .mk (aosp13r76/device/google/tangorpro/device-tangorpro.mk)
# External Camera
# Camera configuration file. Shared by passthrough/binderized camera HAL
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += android.hardware.camera.provider@2.4-impl
# Enable binderized camera HAL
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += android.hardware.camera.provider@2.4-service
# Enable external USB camera
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += android.hardware.camera.provider@2.4-external-service
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \
    device/google/tangorpro/external_camera_config.xml:$(TARGET_COPY_OUT_VENDOR)/etc/external_camera_config.xml

Add the external camera provider name to the device manifest (aosp13r76/device/google/tangorpro/manifest.xml)
<hal format="hidl">
   <name>android.hardware.camera.provider</name>
   <transport>hwbinder</transport>
   <version>2.4</version>
   <interface>
      <name>ICameraProvider</name>
      <instance>external/0</instance>
      <instance>legacy/0</instance>
      </interface>
</hal>

** Add the external camera configuration file aosp13r76/device/google/tangorpro/external_camera_config.xml **
<ExternalCamera>
    <Provider>
        <ignore> <!-- Internal video devices to be ignored by external camera HAL -->
            <id>0</id> <!-- No leading/trailing spaces -->
            <id>1</id>
        </ignore>
    </Provider>
    <!-- See ExternalCameraUtils.cpp for default values of Device configurations below -->
    <Device>
        <!-- Max JPEG buffer size in bytes-->
        <MaxJpegBufferSize bytes="3145728"/> <!-- 3MB (~= 1080p YUV420) -->
        <!-- Size of v4l2 buffer queue when streaming >= 30fps -->
        <!-- Larger value: more request can be cached pipeline (less janky)  -->
        <!-- Smaller value: use less memory -->
        <NumVideoBuffers count="4"/>
        <!-- Size of v4l2 buffer queue when streaming < 30fps -->
        <NumStillBuffers count="2"/>

        <!-- List of maximum fps for various output sizes -->
        <!-- Any image size smaller than the size listed in Limit row will report
            fps (as minimum frame duration) up to the fpsBound value. -->
        <FpsList>
            <!-- width/height must be increasing, fpsBound must be decreasing-->
            <Limit width="640" height="480" fpsBound="30.0"/>
            <Limit width="1280" height="720" fpsBound="15.0"/>
            <Limit width="1920" height="1080" fpsBound="10.0"/>
            <!-- image size larger than the last entry will not be supported-->
        </FpsList>
    </Device>
</ExternalCamera>

Flash my aosp and kernel build on a Pixel tablet
The external camera is not detected after these steps; Camera 2 API is still accessing the internal cameras only
